# What is the order of schema locations (xsd:import) generated in a WCF WSDL?

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I'm generating a custom address for the schemaLocation attribute of the xsd:import statements in a WSDL. Is there an easy way to determine which xsd selector corresponds to which namespace?

For example, the wsdl generated automatically by WCF contains

```
   <wsdl:types>
      <schema targetNamespace="http://www.xyx.com/myService/Imports" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <import schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com/vdir/myService.svc?xsd=xsd1"
         namespace="namespace0" /> 
        <import schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com/vdir/myService.svc?xsd=xsd0" 
         namespace="namespace1" /> 
     </schema>
   </wsdl:types>
```